# Логика создания контрагента и одновременно заказа

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, плиз, разобраться как правильно логику определить:
Чтобы создать карточку заказа, нужно прикрепить к нему клиента (он может быть повторным или новым).
У меня в голове только одно - сначала создаем клиента (или выбираем повторного из базы данных) и потом создаем заказ.
Можно ли как то объединить эти два этапа?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Оптимальный вариант - хранимая процедура. Как в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1347154/229437) [phpBear](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/467825/phpbear). Возможно и решение с использованием триггера - но вот проблема, если клиента нет и его надо создать, то для его создания нужны некоторые данные, которые в запросе на вставку заказа просто нет. Эти данные можно передать, используя определённые ухищрения, но стОит ли овчинка выделки?

Answer (score 1):

Без структуры БД это конечно гадание на кофейной гуще, но все же попробую.
Предположим у Вас вот такая структура БД

```sql
-- справочник заказов
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(255)
  ...
);
-- справочник клиентов
CREATE TABLE clients (
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  jur_address varchar(255),
  real_address varchar(255),
  ...
);
-- связка заказов с клиентами (один-ко-многим)
CREATE TABLE lnk_client_orders (
  id bigint not null auto_increment,
  client_id bigint int not null,
  order_id bigint int not null,
  ...
);
```

Предположим создали Вы заказ. Теперь его нужно как-то связать с клиентом - но Вы его не знаете, до тех пор пока не создадите или не получите из БД. Все как Вы и описали. Тут выхода два:

1. Традиционный - создаем заказ, запоминаем ИД, создаем/получаем клиента - запоминаем ИД. Связываем эти два ИД через таблицу связку.
2. Пишем на стороне БД процедуру `create_order` в которую передаем данные о заказе и клиенте - и она уже внутри себя сама решает - что создать или получить и как связать.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE create_order 
(
   order_name varchar(255),
   client_id bigint,
   client_name varchar(255),
   ...
) 
BEGIN 
   DECLARE order_id bigint;
   INSERT INTO orders (name) VALUES(order_name);
   SELECT INTO @order_id LAST_INSERT_ID();
   --  если указан client_id получаем о нем информацию (проверяем что такая запись есть)
   -- если он не указан - создаем нового клиента, получаем ID
   -- по аналогии с order_id и связываем клиента и заказ путем
   -- INSERT в таблицу-связку
END;
```

На мой взгляд предпочтительней второй вариант т.к он решает за Вас большую часть проблем с проверками - плюс его реализация скрыта `под капотом`, что не позволит в случае `чур меня` - взлома сайта - понять как и что у Вас формируется, и соответственно, что-то накрутить в заказах.

Comment: Спасибо за такое подробное объяснение. 
То есть когда я создал заказ, то уже в нем заполняю форму клиента (новый или повторный), но при этом должен где-то хранить id заказа, чтобы при добавлении клиента сохранить данные в связывающую таблицу?

Comment: Желательно все это делать на одной странице. Для известных клиентов делаете форму авторизации, и после входа Вы будете знать их ИД. Либо если это у Вас внутренняя какая-то система учета, то известного клиента выбирайте из `selectbox` - выпадающего списка. А если клиент новый, то после оформления заказа Вы предлагаете ему зарегистрироваться либо (для внутренней системы) заполняете форму с данными о нем. Данные заказа, если использовать `php` можно хранить в сессии. А по окончании регистрации нового клиента - сохраняете в БД заказ, получаете его ИД и делаете связку с ИД клиента.

Comment: Это внутренняя система как вы отметили. Поэтому в голове только одно витает - как в CRM системах всеми известных: создается сделка, а в ней добавляют контакты клиента (фио, телефон, почту), либо выбирают из базы существующего и далее с этой сделкой работают. У меня получается создался заказ, прикрепили клиента и работаем в карточке заказа, а именно добавляем позиции к этому заказу, условно товар1, товар2, товар3.

Comment: Вариантов как это сделать миллион. Тут все решаете только Вы как разработчик.